# Rcmdr error when loading in OSX Yosemite

Tags: r, macos, r-commander

I'm trying do load Rcmdr and keep getting an error message.

I'm using Rstudio Version 0.98.1091 on a OSX Yosemite operating system.

I have done the following:

```
    install.packages("Rcmdr")
    trying URL'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/Rcmdr_2.1-5.tgz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5342987 bytes (5.1 Mb)
    opened URL
    ==================================================
    downloaded 5.1 Mb
```

However, when I try to load it, I get the following error:

```
    > library(Rcmdr)
    Loading required package: splines
    Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
    Loading required package: car
    Loading required package: sandwich
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:
    call: structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj")
    error: [tcl] invalid command name "tk_messageBox".
    In addition: Warning message:
    In fun(libname, pkgname) : couldn't connect to display ":0"
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’
```

I have already installed X11 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: How long ago did you install X11? Are you on Yosemite? X11 gets borked pretty badly if so. I'd reinstall XQaurtz and try it again. It works fine on my Yosemite system

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Thanks. I have the latest version of XQuartz (2.7.7) and it still doesn't load!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue-- but it ended up working fine as long as I had X11 running prior to opening R.  Now it works fine.  See if that works!

Comment: You can download X11 from XQuartz at the following link: [http://www.xquartz.org](http://www.xquartz.org).  On my Mac it installs in Applications in the "Other" folder (which is where you can find Terminal, Activity Monitor, Grapher, etc.).  A quicker way to access it is to use spot light by holding command and hitting the space bar and then typing in X11, however I prefer Quicksilver for quickly launching apps from the keyboard: [https://qsapp.com/](https://qsapp.com/).